# Grails test war when deployed in tomcat gives ERROR

Tags: grails, verifyerror

Even after increasing heap size I get Perm Gen and also the following error.

I get first the following and after repeated attempts to access my application I get Perm Gen

JDK: 1.6
Grails : 2.0.0
Tomcat 7

I have no clue how to resolve.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/InvokerInvocationException, method: getMessage signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;) Illegal constant pool index
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/InvokerInvocationException, method: getMessage signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;) Illegal constant pool index
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:97)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1054)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:884)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:410)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithApplicationContext(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:489)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doPostProcessing(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:169)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.performPostProcessing(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:232)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:172)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:124)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:104)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a VerifyError which means you problem is most likely a classpath problem, or you compiled using a different Java version to what you are running under.